# What's the difference between these codes? Why do they have different outputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']
s = '/'
newList = s.join(list)
print(newList)
```

This code outputs

```
"first/second/third/fourth"
```

---

```
list = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']
s = '/'
newList = s.join(str(list))
print(newList)
```

This code outputs

```
 "[/'/f/i/r/s/t/'/,/ /'/s/e/c/o/n/d/'/,/ /'/t/h/i/r/d/'/,/ /'/f/o/u/r/t/h/'/]"
```

What does `str()` do here that causes the list to separate by every letter?

Comment: str basically goes into each element of the list and while iit is converting each character of each string to a string it also joins it by /

Comment: Just check what the difference between `list` (unfortunate name BTW) and `str(list)` is.

Comment: Two pedantic points: `list` is the name of a built-in function in python and should not be used as a variable name, and "code" in this sense is a mass noun and therefore does not take a plural.

Comment: @JonKiparsky, an even more pedantic point: in Python `list` is not a function it is a type.  try `type(list)` and see what you get.

Comment: @StephenRauch thanks for  catching my blunder. (problem exists between brain and fingers)

Answer (score 3):

The `str()` create a string like `"['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']"`.

And `s.join()` treat the string as a char array. Then it put `'/'` between every element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

`str` converts it's argument to its string representation. The string representation of a list is a single string starting with an opening square bracket and ending with a closing one. The elements in between are converted using `repr` and separated by `,`. That string is in itself an iterable of characters. As such, `join` will place a `/` between each element of the iterable, i.e., between every character of the string.

The equivalent to your first code would be to convert every string element of the list into a separate string:

```
s.join(str(x) for x in list)
```

In your particular case, `str` is a no-op because it will return the argument if the input is already a `str`.

For arbitrary lists, the approach shown here *is* better than just using `s.join(list)`, because `join` requires all the elements of the iterable to be `str`s, but makes no attempt to convert them, as say `print` would. Instead, it raises a `TypeError` when it encounters a non-`str`.

Another, less pythonic, but nevertheless very common, way of expressing the same conversion is

```
s.join(map(str, list))
```

And of course, the insert the mandatory admonition against naming variables after common builtins here for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The `join` function is a string method which returns a string concatentated with the elements of a iterable.

Now, in the first case:

```
list_1 = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'] #I changed the name to list_1 as list is a keyword
s = '/'
newList = s.join(list_1)
print(newList)
```

Every string in the list is a iterable, so, join outputs by concatenating all elements of the list by adding `'/'` between each element.

In the second case:

```
list_1 = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']
s = '/'
newList = s.join(str(list_1))
print(newList)
```

Since, `str` converts the entire list including the `[` and `]` braces as a string. Due to this every character in the new string becomes a iterable and join returns a new string by adding `'/'` between every element.